# A Basic and a Normal Question, I wanna create a portfolio Dynamic Super Hot Website Without using wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A Basic and a Normal Question, I wanna create a portfolio Dynamic Super Hot Website Without using WordPress or any other cms, but also on the other Hand the client is not paying me the amount that I should and code and give him enough time, my question is this, is there any other way I can quickly create a dynamic website by not using cms and it's super responsive graded a+ in GtMetrix lighthouse and many more, along with it is super fast.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create a dynamic website with out coding or use a CMS.
CMS like WordPress is super easy and fast to setup.